# Python3でGUIアプリケーションを作るためのライブラリを探しています

Tags: python3, gui

Python3でGUIアプリケーションを作りたいのですが、良いライブラリはありますか?

下記の条件を満たすようなものを探しています

- ライブラリを改変しても公開しなくても良いライセンス (BSDやMITなど)
- Qt Designerのようにデザインが簡単にできるツールがある
- クロスプラットフォーム (Windows, macOS, Linux)
- プロジェクトがメンテされていること

Python3でGUIはいろいろありますがライセンスが微妙だったり、メンテされていなかったりとなかなか上の条件に合うものが見つかりません